# Python prime number list

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out why these two snippets should essentially do the same work, but somehow they do not.

I want to find the prime numbers between 1-100. And I know this could work:

```
# This create an empty list first.
# if number qualifies the prime number then append, if not then break.

pnumber1 = []
for x in range(2, 101):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        pnumber1.append(x)
print(pnumber1)
```

So I was trying to play in another way, that I create a list of all numbers 1-100, and remove the number that is not prime number. Then what's left should be the prime number list. So I have:

```
# note: this code should exclude '2', which is a prime number, I'll worry about that later.

pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            pnumber1b.remove(x)
    else:
        break
print(pnumber1b)
```

Somehow, this won't work, as it will return every number from 3-100. That means the `pumber1b.remove(x)` did not work.

OK, if I try it this way:

```
  pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
    for x in pnumber1b:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if x % i == 0:
                pnumber1b.remove(x)
            else:
                break
print(pnumber1b)
```

to change the indent level, it will still return: `list.remove(x): x not in list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course it will not work : take the example of i=2,x=6 , 6 is not prime ergo you remove it.

on the next iteration of i, i=3 you come across x=6 one again and try to remove it again! so you are getting the error : list.remove(x): x not in list .

**and of course the most important note: you cannot change the list that you are iterating over! when you remove item x from list your next iteration will be invalid and the list will be corrupted!**

try something like adding another if that asks if x is still in pnumber1b:

```
pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
pnumber1a = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
        for i in range(2, x):
                if x % i == 0:
                    if x in pnumber1a:
                        pnumber1a.remove(x)
                        break
                    else:
                        continue

print(pnumber1a)
```

or simply add break after your remove command since there is no need to continue running on the number x.

```
pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
pnumber1a = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
        for i in range(2, x):
                if x % i == 0:
                    pnumber1a.remove(x)
                    break
print(pnumber1a)
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the lesson I learned is that it is better to append item into an empty list than create a list then remove items from it, generally speaking.

Comment: I think your method of creating two identical list to avoid conflict is very good idea to achieve my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Hello actually, your first method will print all the odd number from 3 to 100. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: yes, you are correct , as @jxie0755 and you said - it will not work - the reason is that the else:break that i wrote , since all even numbers will satisfy the condition : if x%i == 0 on the first iteration (since it is 2) , it will remove this numbers.
regarding the uneven numbers - it will fail in the same condition and will go to the else and break - meaning the number will stay in the list and we will move on to the next number - sorry for the confusion .

i will edit my response

Answer (score 1):

There's some unclear behavior that makes your first code work which doesn't happen in the second one.

A `for` loop executes the `else` statement if it manages to finish naturally without a `break`.

This prints "Ok!":

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 11: break  # Condition not reached, loop ends naturally
else:
    print('Ok!')
```

While this doesn't:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5: break
else:
    print('Ok!')
```

If, as you were doing, you do this:

```
pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            pnumber1b.remove(x)
    else:
        break
```

Then it will reach the end of the `for i in range(2, x):` naturally, will trigger the `else` and break out of the outer loop, without checking most values.

You could remove the `else`:

```
pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            pnumber1b.remove(x)
print(pnumber1b)
```

This will fail because on numbers with more than one multiple, it will try to remove the item twice and raise an exception when it doesn't find the item it already removed.

You could then add a break to stop looking for multiples after finding the first one:

```
pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            pnumber1b.remove(x)
            break
print(pnumber1b)
```

And this *would* work except for the fact that removing list items *while iterating over the list* causes problems with the iteration. You'll see that it'll start removing only even numbers.

What does work (but is a bit pointless, given the first example you showed) is creating a new list, adding the non-primes to that list, and then, *after* iterating over the list, removing them:

```
to_remove = []
pnumber1b = list(range(3, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            to_remove.append(x)
            break
for r in to_remove:
    pnumber1b.remove(r)
print(pnumber1b)
```

Comment: So what is the right way again? I tried different indent levels, could not get it right.

Comment: @jxie0755 right; there were some deeper issues I didn't notice with my first answer. See the updated answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

@ddor254

your first set of codes are not right, it will only remove the even number.

I changed it to:

```
pnumber1b = list(range(2, 101))
pnumber1a = list(range(2, 101))
for x in pnumber1b:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            if x in pnumber1a:
                pnumber1a.remove(x)
    else:
        continue
print(pnumber1a)
```

Now this will work

Answer (score 1):

This method requires that you fill in the array with some known prime values. The more primes you add to the list the more accurate the checker will become.

I've ran this against the first 168 prime numbers without it skipping a beat. I do recommend that you grab your own list of prime numbers to test against it and see if anything returns "False" when it should return "True".

```py
def isprime(n):
if n==0 or n==1: return False
testlist = [2,3,5,7,9,11]

grand = 0

for test in testlist:
    if n==test: return True
    elif n%test==0: return False
    else: grand += 1

if grand > 0: return True
else: return False
```

Using this in your favor can be done in this manner:

```py
primearr = []
for x in xrange(1, 1000000):
    if isprime(x) == True:
        primearr.append(x)
```

This code is fast enough for me to run the first 1000000 numbers in about a second or two. Now if you want to view the results then it's best that you throw them into a text document than reading them out (which can freeze or crash Python) like this:

```py
with open('primelist.txt', 'a') as f:
    for prime in primearr:
        f.write('{},'.format(prime))
```

Then you can check the directory where you have Python installed to find the text document unless you specified a directory in the filename like this:

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\yourname\\Desktop\\primelist.txt', 'a') as f:
```

**EDIT**

I know this is a necro-edit but I feel that it's necessary because I did get it to successfully check the first 10,000,000 prime numbers with the same exact prime test list.

I got the first 10,000,000 primes from this source: http://www.primos.mat.br/2T_en.html

```py
primelist = []
with open('first-ten-million-primes', 'r') as r:
primes = r.readlines()

for prime in primes:
    for num in prime.split('\t'):
        primelist.append(int(num))

testlist = [2,3,5,7,9,11]
success, failure = [], []

for prime in primelist:
    grand = 0
    for test in testlist:
        if prime % test == 0 and prime != test: grand += 1
    if grand > 0: failure.append(prime)
    else: success.append(prime)

print('Successes: {}\r\nFailures: {}'.format(len(success), len(failure)))
```

That output returned:

```
Successes: 10000000
Failures: 0
```

This was all on Python 3.6.5 x64.